# How to check size of session in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, session-cookies

I would expect `session.size`, `session.length` or `session.count` to work, but they all return "undefined method". Why, isn't `session` a hash?

That was curiosity. The actual question: is there a way to check the size of session in KB? Currently my sessions are stored in cookies and it has a 4 KB limit, and when it exceeds, it simply stops putting new data in there. It would be nice to know when in happens, to reset the session or remove old data.

Comment: Why are you storing 4KB in your session?! I'm sure there's a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Let's say, it wasn't me, I am just investigating the bug with session overload. Anyway, It happens mostly in development and is quite unlikely to happen with actual users, but it would be nice to have a backup solution.

Comment: I think with calculating you're just fighting the symptoms and not the actual problem: Why are there 4KB in the session? Where do they come from? How can I store these data elsewhere?

Comment: They come from opening **a lot** of new answer pages with creating a new respondent and storing the id in the session (so the answering can be continued later from the same machine). And also there are encrypted strings, but I don't think I should be tinkering with them.

Comment: I think in this case you should use local storage! :)

Comment: Wasn't it removed from rails 4?

Comment: I don't know, it's really simple to implement. see this http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/storing-data-on-the-client-with-localstorage

Comment: I am not sure I am going to do it for the current issue, but it is a useful link, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is how rails get the session size:

Firstly, get the session data, see ([gems/rack/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:352 commit_session](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L352))

```
data = session.to_hash.delete_if { |k,v| v.nil? }
```

Then it will encrypt the data, see ([gems/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:640](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb#L640)):

```
data = @encryptor.encrypt_and_sign(serialize(name, data))
```

Lastly, get the bytes:

```
data.bytesize
```

You can directly get the session `data` but it's hard to encrypt it manually. I usually add a log at the gem code to check the data:

```
options[:value] = @encryptor.encrypt_and_sign(serialize(name, options[:value]))

puts options[:value].bytesize

raise CookieOverflow if options[:value].bytesize > MAX_COOKIE_SIZE
```

Comment: I do not work with rails any more, so I cannot check, but I will accept this anyway, looks good.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer @Simoroshka. I just met the `CookieOverflow` issue so I found this way to check my actual session size usage, which is larger than 4096.

Comment: Seems like you are leaving out some code?
I am getting

    NameError - undefined local variable or method `name' for  #<SiteController:0x00000000062110> 
    data = @encryptor.encrypt_and_sign(serialize(name, data))                                  
                                                 ^^^^: