# Rails how to check size of current session (cookies)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-cookies

I was happily throwing things into the session instead of direct saving into the database (like in multistep forms) and thought those 4kb is more than enough. Since I use Devise I thought it uses some session storage but felt safe until I tried to `p session` and OH!!! My terminal couldn't event print all data from it. That data is hard to understand - there are some items that I pass to it, but also some local routes and other weird things.

So no I wonder how to check the size of it at some stages? I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522082/how-to-check-size-of-session-in-rails) but following that I get `@encryptor` as undefined / nil..

Also tried:

```
@encryptor = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(secret, cipher: encrypted_cookie_cipher, serializer: SERIALIZER)

data = session.to_hash.delete_if { |k,v| v.nil? }
data = @encryptor.encrypt_and_sign(serialize(name, data))
p data.bytesize
```

But then `secret` is undefined:

> undefined local variable or method `secret'

Comment: What's `secret`?, where's defined?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb#L605) - I know its a local variable defined there, but if i copy/paste its definition so `request` will be undefined as well. Or maybe its some kind of global variable in Ruby..?

Comment: You send me to the code, but is the Rails repository, shouldn't it be `ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new('secret', 'signature_secret')`, with secret being a key? String data type object?

Comment: Cmon, no one could explain how to do this..?  @Sebastian Palma - sorry, I dont understand that code so well

Comment: I couldn't :c, I tried yesterday by checking the cookies size, but didn't have luck. Is that what you really want? the cookies size, nothing else?

Comment: Yes, because I am afraid it might exceed 4kb limit, I just want to see how much of it my app uses 'by default', I mean gems etc. I want to know how much data it is safe to pass to my sessions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried to find a way to display the cookie-size with rails, without success.
But another way to check the size of your current session cookie is the [developer tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/cookies) in the browser.

[image]

There you can see all cookies with some information and its sizes.
It's maybe not the best way, but better than nothing.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge is that the size in bytes, so 422b -> 0,422 kb. Like you wrote.